# Image loading from internet is not displaying properly?

Tags: android, url, imageview

I am displaying an image in a image view which is obtained from internet. The problem is its not getting displayed all the time if I view that page 5 time only 3 or 4 times the image is getting displayed (Each time I am downloading image from internet) How do I make it display every time..

```
public Bitmap getDrawable(String url) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        Bitmap x;

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url) .openConnection();

        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

        x = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return x;
    }

for (int i = 0; i < imageSourceArray.length - 1; i++) {
        detailedArticleImageViewArray[i] = new ImageView(
            ArticleActivity.this);
        System.out.println(TMI + imageSourceArray[i + 1]);
        Bitmap image = getDrawable(TMI + imageSourceArray[i + 1]);
        detailedArticleImageViewArray[i].setImageBitmap(image);
        detailedArticleImageViewArray[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 250));
        detailedArticleImageViewArray[0].setPadding(5, 10, 10, 5);
                }
```

I am getting IOException Buffered InputStream is closed...

One other reason is decode return null or false...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to display image from url then use this.

```
Bitmap mbmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new java.net.URL("urlname").openStream());
Imageview_ref.setImageBitmap(mbmp);
```

I thnk there is no need to download everytime to display image .

Comment: That's not the problem here I am getting "IOException BufferedInput Stream is closed" error when i reopen the page it shows the image...

Comment: Bitmap mbmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new java.net.URL("urlname").openStream());
in this line I am getting IOExcetion

Comment: I have printed the image url its ok not null ?

Answer (score 0):

use this class

```
static class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        super(inputStream);
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
        while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
            long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
            if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                int b = read();
                if (b < 0) {
                    break; // we reached EOF
                } else {
                    bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                }
            }
            totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
        }
        return totalBytesSkipped;
    }
}
```